# Array of infinity annotation objective c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, dictionary, annotations, mkmapview

I need to make an array of infinity annotations on a map. The user adds an annotation, saves it on web and next time anyone loads the app, there is a new annotation. So its like infinity annotations. I'm really stuck. Anyone have an algorithm or a code? Thanks.

Comment: Infinity is ambitious. You need some kind of filtering to limit the response from the server. But you haven't given any details of what this might be based on. Perhaps https://github.com/MarcoSero/MSMapClustering

Comment: It's more like having an unlimited number than actually having an infinite number of them. Right now you have 1, tomorrow you may have a million, you'll never have infinity.
Which part are you stuck on? How to store them to the internet, how to pull them back, how to create them?

Comment: I have a server and I already connected it. I'm stuck on the basic algorithm, not the code. I can't think about something that can make it.....